# How to generate serial numbers up to a specified range of 11 digits?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am using the given code to generate a serial number into Listview up to a specific range of 11 digits. Up to ten digits, the serial is generated like 0333624140 to 0333624160 (such as 0333624140,0333624141,0333624142,0333624143 etc.), but if we change the required value to 11 digits like 03336241441 to 03336241450 then the app crashes.

```
btngenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int value1;
        int value2;
        value1 = Integer.parseInt(txtfirst.getText().toString());
        value2 = Integer.parseInt(txtsecond.getText().toString());
        for(int i=value1;i<=value2;i++){
            list.add(""+i);
            li.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: put the whole generation code in a try catch so you what is the error since it ain't provided in the post.

Comment: you sure int has enough space ?

Comment: What is the maximum possible value of an `int`? How many digits in that max number?

Comment: [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: See this code: https://ideone.com/AwxQ35

Comment: In Logcat following error show me   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "03336241441"

Comment: int max value is up to 10 .(2147483647)

Comment: What substitutes can be used instead of int?

Comment: `long` would work well.  You'll need to write `Long.parseLong` instead of `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: for (long i = value1; i <= value2; i++) {
                list.add(String.format("%011d", i));

Comment: anybody have solution for this.  Long Using is also useless .

Comment: Isn't there a bigint ? And how would a list be able to host so many strings?

Comment: I have made the following changes in the code. This time also the value contains 11 characters such as 03336241441 but the answer is coming in 10 digits and the leading zero has been removed( such as 3336241441) for(Long i = (Long) value1; i<=value2; i++){

Comment: With value1=0 and value2=10000000 you will put only ten million values in a list. Any use for that?

Comment: Any child can tell you the next value of 543234789456783453. It"s pretty easy to write some code that does the same and comes up with 543234789456783454.

Comment: Also any child can add up 543234789456783453 and 3234789456783. It wil just write them below each other on a piece of paper and start at the right adding up two digits. You can write code to do the same.

Comment: There is some work in my office in which sometimes I have to prepare a list of mobile numbers of users and you know that some countries have 10 digit mobile numbers and some have 11 digits etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the solution that I needed by myself and with the help of all of you. I am presenting it here so that someone else can get information about it. Anyway, thank you all from the bottom of my heart۔

```java
btngenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            long value1;
            long value2;
            value1 = Long.parseLong(txtfirst.getText().toString());
            value2 = Long.parseLong(txtsecond.getText().toString());

            for(Long i = (Long) value1; i<=value2; i++) {
                list.add(String.format("%011d", i));
                li.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a totally broken idea for how to code this.  You're creating an array that can be every number that's 11 digits long.  That's 11 billion items.  Even if every object only takes up 8 bytes (4 for the value, 4 for the reference.  And it will be more than that in reality), that's 88 billion bytes, or approximately 9.5 GB.  That will never fit in memory, you're going OOM WAY before that.

There's ways to do this.  Your adapter doesn't need to have an array of every item in it, since it's one continuous range it only needs the start and end index and can calculate the value of each index from the start index and offset.  But having a list of every value is not ever going to work.

Comment: I have already thought so. I know we need to check the difference between the digits we want to get the list by difference. But  I want to make today's experience the reason for my knowledge growth.

Answer (score 0):

In *Java*, the *[int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)* *data-type* utilizes a *32-bit* *[container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)*, reserving a bit for a signum, when negative.
The maximum value, would be *2 <sup>31</sup> − 1*, or *2,147,483,647*.
*[Integer (Java SE 21 & JDK 21) – MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)*.

The typical solution here, is to use the *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)* *class*, which provides an unlimited accuracy.

Here is an example.

```java
List<String> generate(String a, String b) {
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger(a), y = new BigInteger(b), i = x;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = Math.max(a.length(), b.length());
    String f = "%0" + w + "d";
    while (i.compareTo(y) <= 0) {
        list.add(f.formatted(i));
        i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    return list;
}
```

And, here is an example usage.

```java
for (String s : generate("03336241441", "03336241450"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
03336241441
03336241442
03336241443
03336241444
03336241445
03336241446
03336241447
03336241448
03336241449
03336241450
```